# Syncing online and offline stock levels

Tags: algorithm, synchronization, e-commerce

We have an e-commerce site, and several bricks & mortar stores.

I have managed to extract stock data from the "bricks & mortar" database and send this up to the website, but putting the online sales back into the database is proving almost impossible. No docs + uncooperative vendor.

What happens at the moment is the website sells something, the order is processed manually into the store database and then the stock levels are updated back to the website. The issue being that the stock levels are not updated instantly so there is a possibility 2 people can purchase the same item, especially with sale items where there is only a single item left.

I am wondering if there are any good solutions to this?

One thought I had was to store the number of purchases on the website, and subtract that from the number of items in-stock leaving the correct stock level. But then once the order is processed in the "bricks & mortar" store, the stock level being exported to the website would be inclusive of that difference, and my online stock levels would be incorrect.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should use a 'lock' and 'confirm' approach. If a customer at one POS is requesting an item, you should contact the server and lock up the item if it is available. Then customer will have a few seconds to 'confirm' the sale (otherwise the POS requests the server to unlock the item).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, maybe I need to rewrite it.